# How to modify PROMPT to include variables?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, prompt

Here is a simplified version of what I need...
if I set a variable and set it as my PROMPT, like this:

```
set myvar=AAA
PROMPT %myvar%$g
```

gives me:

```
AAA>
```

but then, I want to change my variable and consequently the prompt, so:

```
set myvar=BBB
```

should produce as my PROMPT:

```
BBB>
```

but, it is still

```
AAA>
```

How do make it dynamic?

Comment: set the prompt again. setting a prompt expands/replaces any variables, and then the variables are GONE. the shell will not remember which variables you used or continually check if they've changed.

Comment: The reason for this, is to always display specific important variables, if they are changed programmatically by some script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to *directly* do that; however, you may easily get an equivalent result if you write your own "shell". For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
   echo/
   set "command="
   set /P "command=%myvar%>"
   call %command%
goto loop
```

Output example:

```
>set myvar=AAA

AAA>echo %time%
14:42:12.32

AAA>set myvar=BBB

BBB>echo %date%
10/12/2015

BBB>exit
```

Comment: hmm... interesting approach, it means each command I execute will have to go thru "call %command%" (it might work), also Ctrl+c cancels this window, anyway to avoid it, I would like to use it as a regular command windows.

Comment: As I said, there is not a standard way to do this. You may cancel a command with Ctrl+C and not cancel this Batch file/window if you change `call %command%` by `cmd /C %command%`